# How to uncheck and suppress other checkboxs on a userform?

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, userform

I have a userform with a lot of controls (Checkboxes , OptionButtons ,…).
But my concern here about only 3 checkboxes combined in one frame. 
The names of the respective checkboxes are **A1_CB** , **B2_CB** , **C3_CB** 
The cited checkboxes have a click event code either value of each CB is True or False. 
I need at most only one check from them to be true on a time, 
**Meaning** if A1_CB = True and I clicked B2_CB then both (A1_CB & C3_CB) = false , 
and If possible **suppress** codes of (A1_CB & C3_CB) when they are unchecked.

I tried this code but it has no effect and loop itself:

```
Private Sub A1_CB_Click()
 
    Me.B2_CB.Value = False
 
End Sub
 
Private Sub B1_CB_Click()
 
   Me.A1_CB.Value = False
 
End Sub
```

As always, grateful for all your help.

Comment: If this is what you want, you should use radio buttons instead of check boxes. Their natural behavior is exactly what you need (if they are in the same group). But  it can be done for the three check boxes, too. If I remember well, events do not work on a form, so you should create some boolean variables to be used in order to not let the others event codes doing their job. If you share the workbook in discussion, or a dummy one having the respective user form imported, I think I can help... And I cannot understand how `Me.B2_CB.Value = False` does not work. Only if some other code changes it.

Comment: I have to agree with @FaneDuru ... instead of forcing this to work with checkboxes you should use radio buttons, they already have your desired functionality without you having to do anything. If you still want to do this with checkboxes i can give you an example...

Comment: @Nikita Meier ,the idea behind these three checkboxes that I can run two macro for each one , either it's true or false

Comment: Please, test the adapted code I posted. Please, download from [here](https://easyupload.io/o50agk) your updated workbook and send some feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code dealing with the three text boxes should look like this:

```
Option Explicit

Private boolNoEvents As Boolean

Private Sub A1_CB_Click()
    If Not boolNoEvents Then
        If Me.A1_CB.Value = True Then
          boolNoEvents = True
            Me.B2_CB.Value = False
            Me.C3_CB.Value = False
          boolNoEvents = False
        End If
        Debug.Print "A1_CB has been changed", Me.A1_CB.Value
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub B2_CB_Click()
     If Not boolNoEvents Then
        If Me.B2_CB.Value = True Then
             boolNoEvents = True
              Me.A1_CB.Value = False
              Me.C3_CB.Value = False
            boolNoEvents = False
        End If
        Debug.Print "B2_CB has been changed", Me.B2_CB.Value
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub C3_CB_Click()
    If Not boolNoEvents Then
        If Me.C3_CB.Value = True Then
             boolNoEvents = True
                Me.A1_CB.Value = False
                Me.B2_CB.Value = False
            boolNoEvents = False
        End If
        Debug.Print "C3_CB has been changed", Me.C3_CB.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

The above solution assumes that you want changing the other two check boxes value in `False` **only if the respective check box is checked** (each value becomes `True`)...

Comment: Excellent Work , especially you have found a trick to **suppress** codes of other checkboxes when they are unchecked (from other checkbox , the clicked one)

Comment: With e.g **A1_CB** I added after boolNoEvents = False `Else  MsgBox "Code if A1 is False"`  and that works ok.
But, If I need to run a code if A1_CB equal to True , should I put it between (boolNoEvents = True ….. boolNoEvents = False) Or outside it.

Comment: @Waleed Instead of `Debug.Print "B2_CB has been changed", Me.B2_CB.Value`, above or below it... The meaning of this code line was to show that it runs **only when that specific check box value is manually changed**, not if its value is changed through the others events...

Answer (score 1):

A more generic attempt: Use one central routine that does the work. If you want to add a box, simply change the array definition.

```
Private Sub A1_CB_Click()
    SetCheckboxes Me.A1_CB
End Sub

Private Sub B2_CB_Click()
    SetCheckboxes Me.B2_CB
End Sub

Private Sub C3_CB_Click()
    SetCheckboxes Me.C3_CB
End Sub


Private Sub SetCheckboxes(ClickedBox As Variant)
    Dim checkBoxNames()
    checkBoxNames = Array("A1_CB", "B2_CB", "C3_CB")
    
    ' Prevent recursive call
    Static EventRunning As Boolean
    If EventRunning Then Exit Sub
    EventRunning = True
    
    ' Loop over all checkboxes
    Dim checkBoxName As Variant, checkBox As Variant
    For Each checkBoxName In checkBoxNames
        If checkBoxName <> ClickedBox.Name Then
            Set checkBox = Me.Controls(checkBoxName)
            ' If "clickedBox" was checked, reset value of other boxes.
            If ClickedBox.Value Then checkBox.Value = False
        
            ' If you want to Enable/Disable the other CheckBoxes:
            '' checkBox.Enabled = Not ClickedBox.Value
            
            ' If you want to hide the other CheckBoxes:
            '' checkBox.Visible = Not ClickedBox.Value
        End If
    Next
        
    EventRunning = False
End Sub
```

Comment: It works correctly to uncheck the two other checkboxes.(up voted.)
I chose the other answer by because it has an additional trick to **suppress** codes of other checkboxes when they are unchecked (from other checkbox , the clicked one)